Model with delays
I have to program two models of bone regeneration, one without delays, which is an ordinary differential equation, with which I have not had any problems, and the other model is a differential equation with delays, for which I am using the ddeint library. I have implemented the following code:
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ddeint import ddeint

def komarova_model(y, t, alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2, gamma11, gamma12, gamma21, gamma22):
    u1, u2 = y
    du1dt = alpha1 * u1**gamma11 * u2**gamma21 - beta1 * u1
    du2dt = alpha2 * u1**gamma12 * u2**gamma22 - beta2 * u2
    return [du1dt, du2dt]

def dde_model(Y, t, alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2, gamma11, gamma12, gamma21, gamma22, tau1, tau2):
    u1, u2 = Y(t)  # current state
    u1d, u2d = Y(t - tau1) if t > tau1 else [u1_0], Y(t - tau2) if t > tau2 else [u2_0]
    du1dt = alpha1 * u1**gamma11 * u2d[0]**gamma21 - beta1 * u1
    du2dt = alpha2 * u1d[0]**gamma12 * u2**gamma22 - beta2 * u2
    return [du1dt, du2dt]

def history(t):
    return np.array([u1_0, u2_0])

# Parámetros para ambos modelos
alpha1 = 3
alpha2 = 4
beta1 = 0.2
beta2 = 0.02
gamma11 = 1.1
gamma22 = 0
gamma12 = 1
gamma21 = -0.5
tau1 = tau2 = 0.1

# Condiciones iniciales
u1_0 = 12  # Densidad inicial de osteoclastos
u2_0 = 250  # Densidad inicial de osteoblastos

t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 10000)
sol_komarova = odeint(komarova_model, [u1_0, u2_0], t, args=(alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2, gamma11,         gamma12, gamma21, gamma22))

dde_sol = ddeint(dde_model, history, t, fargs=(alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2, gamma11, gamma12, gamma21,    gamma22, tau1, tau2))

# Graficando los resultados
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

# Comparación de osteoclastos
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(t, sol_komarova[:, 0], 'k-', label='Komarova model (no delay)')
plt.plot(t, dde_sol[:, 0], 'r--', label='Model with delays')
plt.title('Osteoclasts without and with delays')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('Osteoclasts')
plt.legend()

# Comparación de osteoblastos
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(t, sol_komarova[:, 1], 'b--', label='Komarova model (no delay)')
plt.plot(t, dde_sol[:, 1], 'g-.', label='Model with delays')
plt.title('Osteoblasts without and with delays')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('Osteoblasts')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

With this code I have managed to plot correctly the Komarova model (without delays), however the model with delays grows very fast and very fast and then stabilises and it should not be like that, it should be like the Komarova model but with delays, in smooth waves.
Please, if someone can help me to find the error, I would be very grateful. The initial parameters cannot be changed, as they are the ones I have been asked for.
Correct graphic 
Incorrect graphic
I have tested the code I have written and I hope someone can tell me why it is growing out of control.

maybe you should ask on similar portals for DataScience or CrossValidated
